# Using the Facebook GRAPH API, can i find out how long two users have been friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know the date that two people became friends. assuming i can get any kind of permissions from the user, is there a way to find this out. I want to be able to calculate how long people have been friends. perhaps friends since a certain time. etc. I cant figure out if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

no theres no such information in the documented tables of fql and graph api.
you would have to observer the friendslist and mark the time of when a new friend shows up in your own application